# Replace Single Quotes in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an Html String in which i have some elements having single quotes.When i put this inside a $('varHtml'); Since the varHtml already contains some single quotes it qives an error, Can Somebody help me how to Escape the single quotes in the varHtml

Thanks in Advance

Thomson

Comment: Could you give an example error case?

Comment: Can you clarify? $('varHtml') is looking for elements of tag name "varHtml" which clearly don't exist. I believe jQuery only treats its parameter as an HTML string if it contains angle brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a HTML string in a variable, then you don't need to put it in quotes:

```
var varHtml = "<div id='foo'></div>";
$(varHtml);
```

Comment: This is the string which i am having varHtml = "<img title="Go Search" onmouseover="this.src='/Style%20Library/Images/sg_search_but.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/Style%20Library/Images/sg_search_but.gif'" alt="Go Search" src="/Style%20Library/Images/sg_search_but.gif" border="0"></a>" if i add a double quote in forming the string all the attributes will cause a problem if i add a single quote in forming the string the onmouseover and onmouseout attribute will create trouble –

Answer (score 0):

javascript lacks something like an htmlencode to run client side. So you will have to use one of the script libraries. You can try this jQuery solution:
http://www.edentity.ca/WhoWeAre/Blog/Easy-Client-Side-html-EncodeDecode-using-jQuery.aspx
Or you could simply use a javascript string replace function like the one explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp. Replace ' with &#39; or the HTML code you prefer. Reference: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: you never need to htmlencode in javascript. you can set the text of an element using `element.innerText` or `$(element).text()`. Similarly, attributes never need to be encoded either: `element.setAttribute('blah', '<\'">& ')` will work.

Comment: This is the string which i am having

varHtml = "<img title="Go Search" onmouseover="this.src='/Style%20Library/Images/sg_search_but.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/Style%20Library/Images/sg_search_but.gif'" alt="Go Search" src="/Style%20Library/Images/sg_search_but.gif" border="0"></a>"

if i add a double quote in forming the string all the attributes will cause a problem
if i add a single quote in forming the string the onmouseover and onmouseout attribute will create trouble